# Calculate the shaded area under the curve above and below a threshold using trapz and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, area, curve

[image]Im trying to find the area of the shaded parts of the curve. Blue for above the threshold and grey for below it. In the script you can change the ratio of blue to grey by adjusting the level value. When level is set to 2 (pic 1) the areas should be equal. When level is set to 1.6 (pic 2) the blue should have greater area than the grey, etc... Any thoughts on how to find the areas under the curve below and above the threshold?

pic 1:
[image: pic 1]

pic 2:
[image: pic 2]

My code:

```
%% Example 
x = 0:.01:4*pi;% x data
y = sin(x)+2;% y data
level = 2;% level
plot(x, y)
hold on
x_interest = 0:.01:x(length(y));
y_interest = sin(x_interest)+2;
xlim ([0 x(length(y))])

% Shaded area above level
area(x_interest, max(y_interest, level), level, ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.6 .7 .8], ...
    'ShowBaseLine', 'off');

% Shaded area below level
area(x_interest, min(y_interest, level), level, ...
    'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [.5 .5 .5], ...
    'ShowBaseLine', 'off');

%%== This did not work ==%%
above = find(y_interest >= level);
below = find(y_interest <= level);
A_above = trapz(above)
A_below = trapz(below)

 %% Integrate
 plot(x, sin(x)+2)
 fun = @(x) sin(x)+2; 
 integral(fun, 0, x(length(y)))

 A = trapz(x,y)
```

Comment: It seems all your missing is `A_above = trapz(x_interest(above),y_interest(above))` and likewise for `A_below`.

Comment: @user7411032: Thank you for a very well articulated question. I wish more of us followed your example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general sense, the function `trapz(x,y)` (where `x` and `y` are vectors of same length) estimates the area under the curve `f(x) = y`. This area is sandwiched by the function `f(x)` and the x-axis.

For `A_above`, you want to estimate the area between curves `f1(x_interest) = max(y_interest, level)` and `f2(x_interest) = level`. That is same as the area under curve `f1(x_interest)` shifted down by `level`. So this can be evaluated by:

```
A_above =  trapz(x_interest, max(y_interest, level)-level)
```

Similarly, for `A_below`:

```
A_below = -trapz(x_interest, min(y_interest, level)-level)
```

Comment: @ aksadv: Thanks for the help, that did the trick! I really appreciate it, and also appreciate the explanation of how trapz is evaluating the curve. Very useful information. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Hey I was working with this yesterday and wanted to compare it against the integral function in MATLAB and found that I was only getting half the value when the level is set to 1 (making the blue curve complete without grey) 12.56. However when I take the integration of sin(x)+2 I get 25.12. So I tried trapz(x,y) and get 25.12, same as the integration, which makes sense. So not sure why I lose half the value using your suggested method. Any thoughts? I added the code with the integration in my edited section.

Comment: @user7411032: `integral` and `trapz` compute the area between the function (`y = sin(x) + 2`, in this case) and x-axis, whereas, originally, you wanted to compute the area between the function and the `y = level` line. If you draw them out carefully, you'll see that the bottom of the shaded region is different in the two cases.

Comment: @ aksadv: I completely agree, however, shouldn't the trapz = integral when level is set to 1 (see top pic)? If I plot y = sin(x)+2 and take the integral, I get the area under the curve 25.12, like you said. I also get the same using trapz(x,y). But using your method, shouldn't I get the same if I set the level to 1, which makes the blue shaded section = area under the curve for sin(x)+2 using the integral function?

Comment: @user7411032: `trapz(x, y - level)` would equal `integral` when `level` is 0 (not 1). Look at your current [top plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXuF3.png). The shaded area is 12.56 (i.e. half of the entire plot area which is 12.56 units wide and 2 units tall), which is correctly given by the `trapz` based formula with level correction. I apologize if I am not able to correctly understand your point. Do not hesitate to keep asking questions.

Comment: @ aksadv: Ah ha...I see what you're saying. Yes you're correct; I had a "duh" moment. Thanks again for your willingness to be helpful, I really appreciate this. I needed to make sure I understood exactly how these functions work, as the curves I will be applying them to are much more complicated, and need to make sure the numbers I get make sense. I may have more questions in the near future. I'll use this thread for those that pertain to these type of questions. Thanks again, cheers!